# Error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: ”cacert.pem” CApath: none

Tags: error, ssl

I get this error when trying to connect to Magento's Marketplace.
At first, it told me that the problem was with my SSL cert. so I've followed the guide "**Local Host Installations using MAMP/XAMPP etc**" of this link and it isn't working yet.

https://yikesplugins.com/support/knowledge-base/i-receive-the-error-ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-why/

Now I get this error:

> error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: ”C:\MyUrl\xampp\php\cacert.pem” CApath: none

Comment: This is a webserver issue, not a Magento issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the existing certificate with the other one here.
https://gist.github.com/VersatilityWerks/5719158/download
 After that:

Extract and add it to xampp\php\ext
Open xampp\php\php.ini
Add this line curl.cainfo='location from the first step' to the end of the file.
Restart and it should be working now.
This is the source link.
http://codeontrack.com/solve-laravelxamppguzzlehttp-curl-error-60-no-sll-certificate/